# How disable SQL Server jdbc driver logging from a java application?

Tags: java, sql-server, logging, jdbc

When I change the application log level to FINE, SQL Servers log also uses it, and, as consequence, I get a lot of unnecessary log messages. How can I turn off SQL Server log messages?

Answer (score 2):

before starts the jdbc connection, change de value of the property:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc");
logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

I ended up using WARNING

Other status are:
SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST, OFF and all

more information at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378517(SQL.90).aspx